# Java If Statement having multiple conditions with && operator not working

Tags: java, android, if-statement

```
private void validate(String userName, String userPassword){
        if((userName == "Admin") && (userPassword == "1234")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else{
            counter --;
            Info.setText(userName + " Number of Attempts Left: "+String.valueOf(counter) + " - " + userPassword);
            if(counter == 0){
                Login.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Whenever i give input as "Admin" and "1234" condition goes to else part. please help me i am beginner in this field.

Comment: Try   if (userName.equals("Admin") && userPassword.equals( "1234")){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> string **[equals()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object#equals(java.lang.Object))** method compares the two given strings based on the
>   data/content of the string.

Try with

```
  if(userName.equals("Admin") && userPassword.equals("1234")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else{
            counter --;
            Info.setText(userName + " Number of Attempts Left: "+String.valueOf(counter) + " - " + userPassword);
            if(counter == 0){
                Login.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you please tell me what's the problem with "=="

Comment: @Mohit == compares the references to the objects, not their value

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya == goes for all primitive types, enums, ...

Answer (score 0):

You should compare strings using `equals` method:

```
"Admin".equals(UserName)
```

BTW, the code above is a bit safer than

```
UserName.equals("Admin")
```

because it does not throw NullPointerException when UserName is null.

Answer (score 0):

**==** tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).

**.equals()** tests for value equality (whether they are logically "equal").

Therefore use .equals(), or equalsIgnoreCase() instead of == for comparing String objects.